# How do I calculate a sum of individual values that fit in a range using the least amount of datums

Tags: python, sorting, math

I am trying to calculate a way to find a sum of numbers that fit into a range using the least amount of data and reach as close to the upper limit as possible. The upper limit receives priority.

```
individualValues = {0.07, 0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.33, 0.45, 0.6 , 1.2}
lowerLimit = 0.8
UpperLimit = 1
```

A good result to this question would be one as close to the upper limit as possible using the least amount of values. I.E
answer = {0.07, 0.6, 0.33}

Comment: You have to try to do it yourself first and, when stuck, upload your error or wrong result for help.

Comment: @HuLuViCa i dont know where to start....

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you need to do, since I am not sure I understand the question completely. It would be nice if you could also give what the expected output is.

Comment: @kesetovic im editing the question to better represent a better answer

Comment: @kesetovic this should suit the question much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a far superior mathematical approach but this seems to work:

```
from itertools import combinations

values = [0.07, 0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.33, 0.45, 0.6 , 1.2]
lowerLimit = 0.8
UpperLimit = 1.0
result = None

for m in range(len(values), 0, -1):
    for combo in combinations(values, m):
        if lowerLimit <= (sc := sum(combo)) <= UpperLimit:
            if result is None or (sc > sr and len(result) > m):
                result = combo
                sr = sc
                
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
(0.07, 0.33, 0.6)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do the values need to be in a set? If not you can put them in a list and then do a for loop to pull values greater than .8 and less than 1 and put them in a new value list

Comment: The values do not need to be in a list, this is a good idea but in certian instances this would not work. 

Lets say you have the individualValues = {0.1, 0.65, 0.35, 0.88} -> your apporach would result in {0.88 or if you apply to lowest number if possible {0.88, 0.1} }, even tho with another apporach your result could be {0.65, 0.35} . 
Your apporach would not give the most appropirate outcome.